# program that converts spelled out numbers in to its digit form. (c++)

Tags: c++14

I am trying to make a program that converts numbers in digit form to spelled out numbers, and also from spelled-out numbers in to digit numbers (numbers from 0-10). So far my program can do the digit to spelled-out convertion, but I am not sure how to do it the other way around. I am grateful for any help. This is my code so far:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <string> string_val = {"zeroe","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven" ,"eight","nine"};
    int integer =0;
    string spelled_integer;

    cout<<"Enter a number bethween '0' and '10'\n";

    while(cin>>integer)
    {
        if(integer<10)
            cout<<"your number in spelled out form is: "<<string_val[integer] <<'\n';
        else
            cout<<"your number is either to low, or to big, try again.\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: have a std::map that maps string (human name of digit) to int

Comment: @pm100 I see, can you give me an example on how to do this? I`m quite new to c++.

Comment: @håkonknudsen see my answer for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@pm100** suggested in a comment, an [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is the perfect solution for you. Here is a sample:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> numbers {
            {"zero", 0},
            {"one", 1},
            {"two", 2}
    };

    std::cout << numbers["two"];
}
```

The above sample prints <kbd>2</kbd>. For the other way around (the one you've already done) I would also suggest using a map. They are very powerful containers worth exploring.

Comment: You have to `#include <map>`

Comment: @Joschi if we are being pedantic, one would also need to `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>`. O omitted the `#include`s for brevity.